# Sturm-Liouville : $y''+\lambda y=0$, $y'(0)=0$ and $y(6)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Initial conditions are in the question. I need to find the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenfunctions.

I got 
$$y(x)=c_1 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda x})+c_2 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda x})$$ 
and used the initial conditions give $$\lambda=\frac{(n \pi)^2}{36}$$ 
but it appears this is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $x$ does not belong under the square root.

Answer (score 1):

$y''+\lambda y=0$.
**Case $1$:** $\lambda=0$
$y''=0\implies y(x)=Ax+B.\quad y(6)=0\implies6A+B=0\implies B=-6A\implies y(x)=A(x-6)$

$y'(0)=0\implies A=0$. So $\lambda=0$ is not an eigen value.

**Case $2$**: $\lambda >0$. Let $\lambda=\alpha^2 \quad 0\ne \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$y''+\alpha^2 y=0\implies y(x)=A\cos \alpha x+B\sin \alpha x \quad y'(0)=0\implies B=0. \quad\therefore y(x)=A\cos \alpha x.\quad y(6)=0\implies A\cos6\alpha=0$

For non trivial solution we must have $\cos 6\alpha=0\implies 6\alpha=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \alpha_n=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{12}$. Correspondingly $\lambda_n=(2n+1)^2\frac{\pi^2}{144}$ which are the eigen values. Now find the corresponding eigen vectors. Then do Case $3$ for $\lambda<0$

Comment: my n values start at 1,2,3 etc.. does this make any difference because apparantly your working isnt quite right according to lecturer

Comment: I didn't quite get you clearly. Can you be clearer as to what is that you want to know and what "apparently" is wrong according to your lecturer ?

Comment: Its ok I found the error. Because n=1,2,3.. ect and doesnt start at 0 the (2n+1) part changes to (2n-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here the differential equation is $$y''+\lambda y=0\qquad \text{with $~y'(0)=0~~$and $~y(6)=0~$}\tag1$$

**Case I:** If $~\lambda~=~0~$, then the given equation becomes $$y''=0\qquad \text{with $~y'(0)=0~~$and $~y(6)=0~$}$$

Solution of the above equation is $~y(x)=~a~x+b\qquad $where $~a,~b~$ are constants.

From the given conditions $~a=b=0~$.

So we get $~y(x)=0~$, which is the trivial solution.

**Case II:** If $~\lambda~=-m^2~\lt~0~$ where $~m\in \mathbb{N}~$,  then the given equation becomes $$y''-m^2~y=0\qquad \text{with $~y'(0)=0~~$and $~y(6)=0~$}$$

Solution of the above equation is $~y(x)=~a~e^{m~x}+b~e^{-m~x}\qquad $where $~a,~b~$ are constants.

From the given conditions again $~a=b=0~$.

So we get $~y(x)=0~$, which is the trivial solution.

**Case III:** If $~\lambda~=m^2~\gt~0~$ where $~m\in \mathbb{N}~$, then the given equation becomes $$y''+m^2~y=0\qquad \text{with $~y'(0)=0~~$and $~y(6)=0~$}$$

Solution of the above equation is $~y(x)=~a~\cos{(m~x)}+b~\sin{(m~x)}\qquad $where $~a,~b~$ are constants.

Now $~y'(0)=0~\implies b=0$

$y(6)=0\implies a\cos(6m)=0$

Now if $~a=0~$, we again get the trivial solution, so we discard this case and let $~a\ne 0~.$

So $~\cos(6m)=0\implies 6m=(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}~~~~~\text{where $~n\in \mathbb{N}~$ }$
$~\implies ~m=(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{12}~~~~~\text{where $~n\in \mathbb{N}~$ }$

So the eigen value of the given differential equation $(1)$ is $$~\lambda=m^2=~(2n-1)^2\frac{\pi^2}{144}~~~~~\text{where $~n\in \mathbb{N}~$ }~$$

and the corresponding eigen functions are $$~y(x)~=~a~\cos\left\{(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{12}~x\right\}\qquad \text{where $~n\in \mathbb{N}~~~$and $~a~$ is a constant}~.$$

---

**You can also take the following**

$~\cos(6m)=0\implies 6m=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}~~~~~\text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }$
$~\implies ~m=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{12}~~~~~\text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }$

So the eigen value of the given differential equation $(1)$ is $$~\lambda=m^2=~(2n+1)^2\frac{\pi^2}{144}~~~~~\text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }~$$

and the corresponding eigen functions are $$~y(x)~=~a~\cos\left\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{12}~x\right\}\qquad \text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~~~$and $~a~$ is a constant}~.$$

**Note:** In both the two cases the values of $~\lambda~$ are same, in the first one $~n~$ does not take the value $~0~$, and in the second case it takes.